# Error en foreach Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

estoy recorriendo un array de datos con un foreach, pero a la hora de recorrerlo me suelta esto Invalid argument supplied for foreach() y me dice que las variables estan indefinidas. Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php 

include 'Models.php';

class Restaurant extends Models{
    private $datos;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->datos=array();
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function InfoRest(){

        session_start();
        $id = $_SESSION['usuario']['id_usuario'];
        $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id_usuario = '$id'");
        $sql->execute();
        if($sql->rowCount()>=1){
            while($row=$sql->fetch()){
                $this->datos[]=$row;
            }
        return $this->datos;
        }else{
            $sql->errorInfo()[2];
        }
    }
}
?>

$obj = new Restaurant();
$values = $obj->InfoRest();
 foreach($values as $value){

 }

<?php echo $value['name_rest'] ?>
```

Al recorrelo me arroja esos errores. Le he dado muchisimas vueltas pero no logro aun solucionar.
He hecho var_dump en el execute y me suelta true,y en el mismo proyecto tengo algo hecho de la misma forma y no arroja error, por ejemplo esto:

```
     class Models{

     protected $pdo;
     private $datos;

     public function __construct(){
        $this->datos=array();
        try{ 
            $this->pdo = new 
     PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vmenu.us;charset=utf8','root','');
            }
            catch(PDOExcepcion $e)
            { 
                echo $e->getMessage(); 
            exit; 
            }
      }

     public function DetailsRestaurant($id){

        $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id_restaurant = :id");
        $sql->bindParam(':id',$id);
        $sql->execute();
        if($sql->rowCount()>=1){
            while($row = $sql->fetch()){
            $this->datos[]=$row;
            }
            return $this->datos;
        }else{
            $sql->errorInfo()[2];
        }

    }
 }
```

Y luego esto en mi Vista:

```
 $obj = new Models();
 $id = $_GET['id_restaurant'];
 $details = $obj->DetailsRestaurant($id);
  foreach($details as $result){
 }

 <?php echo $result['name_rest'] ?>
```

Como ven es lo mismo

Comment: En la función `InfoRest()` no estás retornando nada en caso de que no entre al `if` y siga por el `else`. Al parecer está yendo por ahí y la variable `$values` queda vacía. Probá imprimiéndola `print_r($values)`. Saludos!

Comment: Ya he hecho el print_r y no me imprime nada Genarito

Comment: `<?php echo $value['name_rest'] ?>` ¡está **fuera** del bucle `foreach`!

Comment: Cedano pero es que he hecho muchas veces asi. Imprimiendo las variables fuera del foreach, y no me habia pasado eso! Es mas tengo en el mismo proyecto muchas cosas hechas de esa forma y no me da ese error

Comment: He impreso el $sql->rowCount() y me imprime 0, osea que no esta contando ningun registro pero no entiendo porque, en mi bd si esta ese registro

Comment: @AlejoMendoza, eso comprueba lo que te dije. Probá poniendo un `return Array()` en el else de `InfoRest()` para que devuelva un arreglo vacío en caso de que no puedas obtener nada de la base de datos

Comment: ¿En serioooo? No veo posible que puedas hacer eso, a no ser que dentro del bucle crees o llenes alguna variable y luego la leas fuera de él. @Genarito tiene razón, deberías retornar algo en el `else`, pero mejor pon esto: `return $sql->errorInfo()[2];`, así te imprimirá en pantalla el mensaje de error de **por qué no funciona la consulta**. Te será útil para depuración. También convendría que crees una variable con la consulta: `SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id_usuario = '$id'` y la imprimas podrás verificar que realmente ese usuario existe ejecutando la consulta en la DB directamente.

Comment: Si cedano, he editado la pregunta para que te fijes que imprimo fuera del foreach y no me da problema.

Comment: Bueno, ya vi el error... escribiendo respuesta.

Comment: He hecho lo que me han dicho y ya creo saber que es lo que pasa, estoy planteando mal la consulta

Comment: Respecto al echo fuera del bucle, si puedes, pero solo mostrarás el último elemento del bucle. Otra cosa es el error que te sale, que trata de que en el bucle, $details, no debe de tener nada.

Comment: No @track3r eso es falso. con el echo fuera del bucle puedo mostrar todos los elementos que traiga el array, no solo el ultimo. Lo he hecho muchisimas para mostrar varios datos en una misma tabla o para mostrar un solo dato.

Comment: Vale, creo que ya lo entiendo... tu bucle no vale para nada, es lo mismo que hacer $result = $details si no esoty muy tonto hoy.... aunque depende de lo que sea $details, si es un arreglo entonces solo tomará el último elemento.

Comment: $details es un arreglo, y no trae solo el ultimo elemento. Trae todos los elementos.

Comment: Acabo de hacer un ejemplo simple y no tienes razón o no nos entendemos, hago: $obj = (object) array('1' => 'foo', '2' => 'bar'); foreach($obj as $e) {} echo $e; y sale bar, no foo y bar.

Comment: Lo que creo es que no nos entendemos. Lo hago como he mostrado en la pregunta y me imprime todos los datos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay un error de planteamiento en tu función.
Si quieres verificar que el usuario existe, no necesitas el uso de `numRows`, sino que puedes llenar tu array directamente.

Como en el `else` puedes retornar el mensaje de error, entonces puedes verificar si el array está vacío en el destino.

La función podría quedar así (la he blindado contra inyección SQL).

```
public function InfoRest(){

    session_start();
    $id = $_SESSION['usuario']['id_usuario'];
    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id_usuario = ?");
    $arrParams=array($id);
    $sql->execute($arrParams);

    if($sql){
        while($row=$sql->fetch()){
            $this->datos[]=$row;
        }
        return $this->datos;
    }else{
        return $sql->errorInfo()[2];
    }
}
```

Y en el código para leerla:

```
$obj = new Models();
 $id = $_GET['id_restaurant'];
 $details = $obj->DetailsRestaurant($id);
 print_r($details);

 foreach($details as $result){
      echo $result['name_rest'];
 }
```

**NOTA:** En `InfoRest` yo implementaría otra forma más lógica de devolver los posibles errores, que me permita verificar al recibir los datos si hay alguna clave con error.

En una futura edición de la respuesta podría proponer esa solución si te interesa. No lo hice aquí para no alejarme demasiado de tu código entrando en otros asuntos. La idea es escribir un código que sea coherente.

Si no te interesa en este caso el mensaje de error, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
    if($sql){
        while($row=$sql->fetch()){
            $this->datos[]=$row;
        }
        return $this->datos;
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
```

De ese modo, tanto si no hay datos, como si la consulta falla, retornará `NULL` y al recibir los datos sólo tienes que evaluar la variable:

```
 $obj = new Models();
 $id = $_GET['id_restaurant'];
 $details = $obj->DetailsRestaurant($id);

 if($details){
      foreach($details as $result){
          echo $result['name_rest'];
      }
 }else{
     echo "No se encontraron datos o la consulta falló";
 }
```

---

Si te interesa mostrar al usuario posibles mensajes de errores de la consulta, entonces tendremos tres posibles resultados:

1. Que la consulta no arroje datos
2. Que haya un error en la consulta
3. Que la consulta arroje datos

Una forma coherente de programar aquí sería devolver en todos los casos un array que podría ser `NULL`, tener el mensaje de error con una clave llamada `error` o un array con nuestros datos.

Dado que aquí me parece que la consulta no arrojará demasiadas filas, creo que podemos usar `fetchAll` para simplificar. Así traemos todos los resultados en una variable `$resultado`. También se puede hacer como antes, con el `while`.

La función quedaría así:

```
public function InfoRest(){
    session_start();
    $id = $_SESSION['usuario']['id_usuario'];
    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id_usuario = ?");
    $arrParams=array($id);
    $sql->execute($arrParams);

    if($sql){
        $resultado=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->datos[]=$resultado;
        return $this->datos;
    }else{
        return array ('error'=>$sql->errorInfo()[2]);
    }
}
```

Y cuando recibes los datos, evalúas los tres posibles resultados así:

```
$obj = new Models();
$id = $_GET['id_restaurant'];
$details = $obj->DetailsRestaurant($id);

if(!$detail){
    echo "No se encontraron datos"; 
}elseif (array_key_exists('error', $detail){
    echo $detail['error']; //Imprimirá el mensaje de error  
}else{
      foreach($details as $result){
          echo $result['name_rest'];
      }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto Cedano he mejorado eso para la inyección SQL. Y ademas del mal planteamiento del if, tenia mal planteada la consulta, porque estaba condicionandola mal. Y si me pareceria muy interesante eso de devolver los errores.

Comment: Por cierto Cedano, en el execute puedo pasar ese arreglo en vez de bindear las variables, pero lo he utilizado en INSERT, UPDATE Y DELETE y siempre me a arrojado un error. No se si solo se usa en los SELECT

Comment: @AlejoMendoza ahora muestro una forma coherente de devolver los errores ya que te interesan. En cuanto a pasar los parámetros en el `execute` sí se puede. Pero debes tener en cuenta qué tipos de marcadores estás usando, si de posición `?` o de `:nombre`, porque en base a eso debes construir el array de una forma o de otra.

Comment: Genial eso de retornar NULL, gracias por eso Cedano, y como siempre dices todo sirve para ir depurando.Y bueno si, he utilizado las mascaras :nombre y al pasarle al execute el array me a dado error, por lo que logro entender que con los de posicion es que funciona como has puesto en la respuesta, en cuanto a tu criterio cual de los dos es el mas seguro, el de posición o la mascara, y disculpa que ando haciendo preguntas sobre una pregunta

Comment: @AlejoMendoza he puesto la última posibilidad que comentaba. Espero te sirva. ...En cuanto a los marcadores, ambos son igualmente seguros. Esas dos posibilidades existen en PDO sencillamente porque en algunos casos es mejor usar uno u otro.